# How can I read the return value of add(N) function in my calc function?

Tags: erlang

I am new to Erlang, I need to spawn two process running add function, then add the
two numbers.
assigned value of Process one and two is showing the process id, I need catch the value.

How can I read the return value of add(N) function in my `calc` function?

```
-module(myerl).
-export([calc/1,add/1]).

add(N) ->
    N + 5.


calc(L)

pone = spawn( fun() -> add(A) end),   
ptwo = spawn( fun() -> add(B) end),

Result = Pone + Ptwo,
io:format("result ~p~n", [Result]).
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use message passing. You must send a message back to the calling process with the result. The `spawn` function returns a PID (process identifier) to the newly spawned process, not the result of its execution.

This example should do what you're expecting:

```
calc(A, B) ->
    Self = self(),       % The spawned funs need a Pid to send to, use a closure
    POne = spawn(fun() -> Self ! {self(), add(A)} end),
    PTwo = spawn(fun() -> Self ! {self(), add(B)} end),
    wait_for_response(POne, PTwo, 0).

wait_for_response(undefined, undefined, Sum) ->
    Sum;
wait_for_response(POne, PTwo, Sum) ->
    receive
        {POne, V} -> wait_for_response(undefined, PTwo, Sum + V);
        {PTwo, V} -> wait_for_response(POne, undefined, Sum + V)
    end.
```

Comment: @Shaka if you've found a solution here you should accept an answer

Answer (score 2):

@Soup d'Campbells' explanation is good. I instinctively did something slightly different which, in a toy way, anticipates some bad behavior with the child processes. Also, I allow the input to be a list of numbers, not just 2.

```
-module(myerl).
-export([calc/1, add/1]).

calc(NumList) when is_list(NumList)->
    Parent = self(),
    _Pids = [spawn(fun()-> Parent ! add(ANum) end) || ANum <- NumList],
    collect(length(NumList), 0);
calc(_) -> 
    {error, badarg}.

collect(0, Sum)   -> 
    Sum;
collect(Cnt, Sum) ->
    receive
        N when is_number(N) -> 
            collect(Cnt-1, Sum + N);
        _Bad ->  % returned something that isnt a number
            collect(Cnt-1, Sum)
    after 1000 -> % died or is too slow
        collect(Cnt-1, Sum)
    end.

add(N) -> 
    N + 5.
```

Comment: I went for simplicity, but points for thoroughness. Though I have to point out that if you *really* want to anticipate bad behaviour you should be using `spawn_monitor` or even `Parent ! catch add(ANum)`

Comment: Thanks Jro for your answer. could you please explain this line. I did not get this part  **bold**,  '|| ANum <- NumList]',

Comment: It's a list comprehension and 'says' something like, for each element of NumList, (let it be called ANum), do the stuf to the left of the ||. This is actually a lousy explanation, take a look at http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html